# Display literal timestamp values

Tags: postgresql, ems-sql-manager

We have a timestamp column that, when queried, displays this syntax:

```
12/18/2018 11:27:35 AM
```

However, this makes it confusing as the timestamp actually stores the milisecond values, as well. This means that when querying for '12/18/2018 11:27:35 AM', we return no results unless we use the date_trunc() function.

Is there anyway to force the engine to display the literal value?

We are using SQL Manager for PostgreSQL

Answer (score 1):

Use the To_Char function on your column to set the output display format:

```
to_char(yourColumn, 'mm/dd/yyyy hh:mi:ss.us am')
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks. Is there a way to make that a default so the function does not have to be used?

Edit: as in a database setting or instance setting (coming from a SQL Server background, I'm thinking of properties like SET ANSI_NULLS ON or something)

Comment: I come from an Oracle background, and while oracle has settings to change this at the DB, and Session level I don't know if postgresql does.  The settings I could find didn't seem that fine grained.